Problems with constant int and pointer indicating it
The book that I'm studying now taught me like expected but repl.it shows result as an output
Please let me know why this result came out.
Thank you.
**Output**
MAX=999
MAX=999


**Expected**
MAX=999
MAX=666

#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)

int main(void) {
    const int MAX = 999;
    int *ptr;
    ptr=(int*)&MAX;
    *ptr=666;
    printf("MAX=%d\n",MAX);
    return 0;
}


A side note: you should not disable compiler warnings (like #pragma warning(disable : 4996)) unless you have a very good reason for that.

Why are there two lines of output for one line of printf?

I guess the warning is about something being deprecated? (If this is MS's C compiler )

No, 4996 is just the standard nag that regular stdio.h functions are being used instead of the _s versions provided by Annex K of the standard. It does the same thing as #pragma (_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS). See Security Features in the CRT

That said, you should always use full warnings, e.g. /W3 and then if you need to disable a specific warning, you can use the #pragma warning(xxxx) as you have, or simply add it to the compile string, e..g /W3 /wd4996 (which give you full /W3 warnings and then disables the specific 4996 warning with /wd4996). Either way is fine, but make sure you have /W3 enabled.

You cast away const in order to change the value of a variable declared const. This makes your program have undefined behavior and you should not expect any particular output from that program, be it 999 or 666. It could be 123 or even crash.
The expectation mentioned in the book has no merit and it's probably best to buy a better book.
If your current book is supposed to be a good book, I assume it has an errata or newer edition where this flaw has been corrected.

That book list is broken; it's a mix of recommended books and blacklisted books - the latter are in majority. Long history here... some mod unhelpfully merged the old present post into a complete mess back in 2017 after which I started this meta post: The C book list has gone haywire. What to do with it?  As a result of that, the damn thing got deleted - good riddance. Then some staff rolled back the deletion. And since then the list is no longer maintained, just one guy attempted it.

Since then I just recommend Gustedt - Modern C and only that one. It's not the best book I've read in terms of beginner-friendliness but the author is a recognized expert and besides very active in the C committee. I think he's updating the book to C23 too. And also it is available for free as pdf, you only need to pay if you want a hardcopy.

@Lundin Oh, snap. I removed the link to that list.

Thank you so much for answer to me. Your comment is helped me a lot.

@user28006951 Glad to hear it! You're welcome!
